# Application for encrypting and decrypting files in Java

Tags: java, file, console, gui, caesar-cipher

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121757/application-for-encrypting-and-decrypting-files-in-java-follow-up).)

I have that application for en-/decrypting files. Here, I will post the actual GUI and command line code. In order to run the program refer to [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/coderodde/CaesarFileTool/tree/cfed9c038fad379fdfc6ceaeec6601081a42b574).

Some images:

[image: The main view]

[image: Choosing files]

[image: Entering the key]

My code is as follows:

**App.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ciphertool;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.coderodde.encryption.CipherTools;
import net.coderodde.file.FileTools;

/**
 * This class implements the command line app for encrypting and decrypting 
 * files with a key.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 29, 2016) 
 */
public class App {

    private static final String HELP_MESSAGE = 
     "Usage: java -jar File.jar [-e | -d <key> FILE1 [FILE2 [...]]]\n" +
     "Where       -e   encrypt the files.\n" +
     "            -d   decrypt the files.\n" + 
     "         <key>   the key in decimal; " + 
                      "use prefix \"0x\" for hexadecimal.\n" +
     "If you omit all arguments a GUI is started instead.";

    private boolean graphicalInterfaceRequested;
    private boolean printHelpMessage;
    private Mode mode;
    private int key;
    private String[] args;

    public void processArguments(String[] args) {
        this.args = args.clone();

        if (args.length == 0) {
            graphicalInterfaceRequested = true;
            return;
        }

        if (args.length < 3) {
            printHelpMessage = true;
            return;
        }

        switch (args[0]) {
            case "-e":
                mode = Mode.ENCRYPTING;
                break;

            case "-d":
                mode = Mode.DECRYPTING;
                break;
        }

        if (mode == null) {
            printHelpMessage = true;
            return;
        }

        if (args[1].length() >= 2 && 
           (args[1].startsWith("0x") || args[1].startsWith("0X"))) {
            String keyString = args[1].substring(2).trim().toLowerCase();

            try {
                key = Integer.parseInt(keyString, 16);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                printHelpMessage = true;
                return;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                key = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                printHelpMessage = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean helpMessageRequested() {
        return printHelpMessage;
    }

    public void exec() {
        if (graphicalInterfaceRequested) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { execAsGUI(); });
        } else {
            execAsCommandLine();
        }
    }

    private void execAsGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("File cipher tool");
        JButton buttonEncrypt = new JButton("Encrypt");
        JButton buttonDecrypt = new JButton("Decrypt");

        buttonEncrypt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 40));
        buttonDecrypt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 40));

        buttonEncrypt.addActionListener(
                new MyActionListener(frame, Mode.ENCRYPTING));

        buttonDecrypt.addActionListener(
                new MyActionListener(frame, Mode.DECRYPTING));

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonEncrypt, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonDecrypt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        moveToCenter(frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void moveToCenter(JFrame frame) {
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation((screen.width  - frame.getWidth())  >> 1,
                          (screen.height - frame.getHeight()) >> 1);
    } 

    private void execAsCommandLine() {
        List<File> fileList = getFileList(args);

        switch (mode) {
            case ENCRYPTING:
                encryptAll(fileList, key);
                break;

            case DECRYPTING:
                decryptAll(fileList, key);
                break;
        }

    }

    static void encryptAll(List<File> fileList, int key) {
        fileList.stream().forEach((File file) -> {
            try {
                byte[] data = FileTools.readFile(file);
                byte[] encryptedData = CipherTools.encrypt(data, key);
                FileTools.writeFile(file, encryptedData);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    static void decryptAll(List<File> fileList, int key) {
        fileList.stream().forEach((File file) -> {
            try {
                byte[] data = FileTools.readFile(file);
                byte[] decryptedData = CipherTools.decrypt(data, key);
                FileTools.writeFile(file, decryptedData);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private List<File> getFileList(String[] args) {
        // We subtract 2 in order to omit the fist two arguments in 'args' that
        // are the switch and the key.
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>(args.length - 2);

        for (int i = 2; i < args.length; ++i) {
            fileList.add(new File(args[i]));
        }

        return fileList;
    }

    private String getHelpMessage() {
        return HELP_MESSAGE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            App app = new App();
            app.processArguments(args);

            if (app.helpMessageRequested()) {
                System.out.println(app.getHelpMessage());
                System.exit(0);
            }

            app.exec();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyActionListener.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ciphertool;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import static net.coderodde.ciphertool.App.decryptAll;
import static net.coderodde.ciphertool.App.encryptAll;

/**
 * This class implements the action listener for the GUI buttons.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 1, 2016)
 */
final class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private final JFrame ownerFrame;
    private final Mode mode;

    MyActionListener(JFrame ownerFrame, Mode mode) {
        this.mode = Objects.requireNonNull(mode, "The input mode is null.");
        this.ownerFrame = ownerFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        File[] files = askUserToChooseFiles(mode == Mode.ENCRYPTING ? 
                                            "Choose files to encrypt" :
                                            "Choose files to decrypt",
                                            ownerFrame);
        if (files == null) {
            return;
        }

        String keyString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                       ownerFrame,
                                       mode == Mode.ENCRYPTING ?
                                       "Type in the encryption key:" :
                                       "Type in the decryption key:",
                                       "",
                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if (keyString == null || keyString.isEmpty()) {
            // User cancelled the entry of the key.
            return;
        }

        if (keyString.length() >= 2
                && (keyString.startsWith("0x")
                || keyString.startsWith("0X"))) {
            String keyStringPrepared = keyString.substring(2)
                    .trim()
                    .toLowerCase();

            try {
                int key = Integer.parseInt(keyStringPrepared, 16);

                switch (mode) {
                    case ENCRYPTING: 
                        encryptAll(Arrays.asList(files), key);
                        break;

                    case DECRYPTING:
                        decryptAll(Arrays.asList(files), key);
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new IllegalStateException(
                                "Should never get here.");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        ownerFrame,
                        "\"" + keyString + "\" is an invalid key.",
                        "",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                int key = Integer.parseInt(keyString);
                switch (mode) {
                    case ENCRYPTING: 
                        encryptAll(Arrays.asList(files), key);
                        break;

                    case DECRYPTING:
                        decryptAll(Arrays.asList(files), key);
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new IllegalStateException(
                                "Should never get here.");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        ownerFrame,
                        "\"" + keyString + "\" is an invalid key.",
                        "",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    private File[] askUserToChooseFiles(String title, JFrame ownerFrame) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(title);
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(ownerFrame);

        if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            return chooser.getSelectedFiles();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Mode.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.ciphertool;

/**
 * The enumeration enumerates the function modes of the program.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Mar 1, 2016)
 */
enum Mode {
    ENCRYPTING, 
    DECRYPTING,
}
```

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: What method do you use to encrypt and decrypt?

Comment: @SCriLL Caesar cipher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Specifying a key

From a UX perspective, I think it will help if you can also indicate that the key should either be prefixed with `0x`, so that you will treat it as a hexadecimal value, or it should be an integer.

#### Code duplication

And speaking about parsing the input keys, there's some code duplication in `App.processArguments(String[])` and `MyActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`. You should consider refactoring the integer parsing part out so that it can be shared in both places.

#### Getting a file list

```
private List<File> getFileList(String[] args) {
    // We subtract 2 in order to omit the fist two arguments in 'args' that
    // are the switch and the key.
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>(args.length - 2);

    for (int i = 2; i < args.length; ++i) {
        fileList.add(new File(args[i]));
    }

    return fileList;
}
```

I think it'll be better if a processed `args` array *without* the initial command-line arguments is passed in here. Anyways, assuming if you prefer to keep to the current approach, you can use the familiar stream processing for this too:

```
private List<File> getFileList(String[] args) {
    return Arrays.stream(args)
                    .skip(2)
                    .map(File::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In fact, this will make refactoring easier when `args` no longer have the additional arguments: you can just remove the line `.skip(2)`.